# jQuery Accordian is completely ignoring any settings I make in the javascript call

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I recently added an Accordian to my site for easier viewing and management of content, however it is not behaving and you would initially suspect, firstly it is completely ignoring any settings I make in the javascript call, for example if I change **autoheight** to either **true or false**, absolutely no changes are visibly made.

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header #1</a></h3>
<div>
Lots of content here which would belong to the accordion menu selected, this would be much larger than the other two contents.
</div>

<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header #2</a></h3>
<div>
Not as much as #1, therefore the height is reduced to support that without leaving a huge gap
</div>

<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header #3</a></h3>
<div>
Only about a line of writing, don;t want the huge gap
</div>

</div>
```

Sadly, whatever I do the accordion is absolutely not responsive, I don't want the huge gaps for the smaller contents, and I understand its possible to remove these because they look very very ugly. However, as stated, my script just does not respond.

I have this in the header of my document:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordian" ).accordion({ clearStyle: true, autoHeight: false });
  });
  </script>
```

I would very much appreciate your time in trying to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `<div id="accordion">` but you call `$( "#accordian" )`.

Comment: This is possibly the most ridiculous mistake I have ever made whilst coding, thank you for pointing that out!